# Create custom form button that does not submit webform

Tags: 8, webforms

I have webform created via Webform UI, and it's multi-step webform.

In second step *('personal information')* I add custom button using `HOOK_form_alter` with following code

```
'generate_pdf' => [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Generate PDF'),
    '#limit_validation_errors' => [],
    '#submit' => ['generate_pdf_template'],
]
```

function **generate_pdf_template** takes values from **$form**, **$form_state** inserts them into twig templat, creates PDF and automatically downloads it.

My issue is, that this **generate_pdf** button submits the form and user is not able to send form via original submit button. Can I somehow prevent submission when `generate_pdf` is clicked so user can download PDF and still be able to send webform with original button and webform's handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work.

`#name` and `#submit` are required.

The name makes sure the button does not get confused with other submit buttons.

The `#submit` value calls a custom function you have to create.

`#limit_validation_errors` prevents form validation, which may or may not be useful.

```
  $form['generate_pdf'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Generate PDF'),
    '#name' => 'generatepdf',
    '#submit' => ['::generatepdf'],
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
  ];
```